# pythonic way of inserting many different datapoints into SQL?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to figure out the best (i.e. not error-prone) way to insert data into SQL using `pymysql`.
The data is extracted iteratively from excel files, and there are multiple data types (i.e. SQL fields) extracted from each excel file.

I can think of two options to do this, but neither are particularly elegant.

Preamble:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="me",
  password="my_pw",
  database="myDB"
)

# Make a cursor for the DB
mc = myDB.cursor()
mc.execute('CREATE TABLE table (field_1 INT, field_2 INT, field_3 INT, Unique_iD VARCHAR(255))'
```

Option 1: Place values in a tuple, then insert the tuple into a list iteratively. Update the SQL table using `executemany()`

```
list_of_tuples = [(1,2,3,'uid_1'), (4,5,6,'uid_2')]

sql = """UPDATE table SET field_1=%s, field_2=%s, field_3=%s WHERE Unique_iD=%s"""
mc.executemany(sql, list_of_tuples)
mydb.commit()
```

The downside with option 1 is that it requires the tuple to be in exactly the right order, which can get confusing. However it's reasonably simple compared to option 2, below.

Option 2: Store the data as a list of dicts, where each dict contains just one field:datapoint along with the unique iD

```
my_dict_list = [{'field_1':1, 'Unique_iD':'uid_1'}, {'field_2':2, 'cell_iD':'uid_1'}, {'field_3':3, 'cell_iD':'uid_1'},{'field_1':4, 'Unique_iD':'uid_2'}, {'field_2':5, 'cell_iD':'uid_2'}, {'field_3':6, 'cell_iD':'uid_2'}]

for pos in my_dict_list:
    col = list(pos.keys())[0]
    val = list(pos.values())[0]
    iD = pos['cell_iD']
    
    sql = f'UPDATE table SET {col}={val} WHERE Unique_iD={iD}'
    mc.execute(sql)
    mc.commit()
```

This seems less likely to cause errors since the insertion only happens if the field name matches the key, and the Unique_iD matches uid simultaneously, but the list of dicts is going to get very big very quickly.

Is there a better way to gather/organise the data before inserting it into the SQL table?

Comment: Drop the last method entirely, it's open to SQL Injection

Comment: I don't use MySQL but there are other parameters you can use. If you want to pass a list of dictionaries, you can try `%(param_name)s` and see if your dialect supports it. Then you don't need to care about order. See [paramstyle](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#paramstyle). `:param_name` is also a potential if you're passing dictionaries

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at `%(name)s`.